# Why is this condition not true?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm relatively new to shell scripting and this situation has me puzzled.  I have inserted the shell script, along with the execution/results of the shell script. The bolded "if/then/elif/then/else/fi" condition (last 8 lines of TEST1.sh) are the part of the original script that is not acting as expected.  I did add the echo statement with the elif, for debugging purposes.  At the bottom, I execute the grep command and it returns 1, the expected value, yet when comparing the result to FILECOUNT (which is set to 1), they do not equal.

**TEST1.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
export TERM="xterm"
SDSELIGLOG=/data3/NEI-SCRIPTS/logs/SDSEligWeekly.log
FILECOUNT="1"
#
echo "grep cmd returns result="
grep -c "100%" $SDSELIGLOG
#
if [[ 'grep -c "100%" $SDSELIGLOG' == $FILECOUNT ]]; then
   echo "TRUE"
else
   echo "FALSE"
fi
#
**if [[ `grep "Incorrect login information" $SDSELIGLOG` ]]; then
      echo "FTP Connection Failed!"
   elif [[ 'grep -c "100%" $SDSELIGLOG' == "$FILECOUNT" ]]; then
      echo "Hits elif section of code"
      #Continue script normally
   else
      echo "File transfer process did not complete fully!"
fi**
```

**Execution/Results**

```
sh-4.1$ ./TEST1.sh
grep cmd returns result=
1
FALSE
File transfer process did not complete fully!
sh-4.1$
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: Extending @Cyrus' comment: `[[ ]]` is a bash feature, which /bin/sh may not support. Either change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`, or switch to `[ ]` (and use `=` not `==`, *and* put double-quotes around all variable and command expansions). [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting mistakes like this.

Comment: Thank you both.  Like I said, I'm pretty new to this and I inherited this code.  I actually did quite a bit of searching, but I guess being new, didn't really know how to ask the question properly.  So, do I decide what shell I'm going to use, by what I put in the shebang, or is this just a comment, and the syntax I use is what truly determines which shell I'm using, based on what's available in my /etc/shells file?  In my case, I have /bin/sh
/bin/bash
/sbin/nologin
/bin/dash
/bin/tcsh
/bin/csh

Comment: The shebang (mostly) controls which shell is used; if you use features that shell doesn't support, the script will fail (see [my answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/865874/bin-sh-vs-bin-bash-for-maximum-portability). Note that the shebang can be overridden by explicitly invoking a shell (e.g. `sh scriptname` will use `sh` even if the shebang specifies /bin/bash); you should generally set the shebang correctly and avoid overriding it. Also, this has nothing to do with /etc/shells.

Answer (score 1):

```
elif [[ 'grep -c "100%" $SDSELIGLOG' == "$FILECOUNT" ]]; then
```

These should be backticks, not single quotes.

```
elif [[ `grep -c "100%" $SDSELIGLOG` == "$FILECOUNT" ]]; then
```

Comment: For maintainability, they should be `$(...)`

Comment: `$( )` is generally preferred over backticks -- it's less visually ambiguous (the cause of this problem) and also doesn't have the slightly odd quoting/escaping syntax that you get within backticks.